# Android Facebook integration: Failed to complete gradle execution. No Cause

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to integrated Facebook sign in to my application. If I added below lines to my build.gradle file for the application:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

in dependencies

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
```

After that if I rebuild project it rebuilds it successfully. But when I try to run it takes long time to build and then shows dialog with text:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Casue:
```

Though the Message Gradle Build windows does not show any error. Here is the output of it

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk420Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareTextvalidatorLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareThreepioLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Quickstart Plugin cannot function without it.
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
Information:0 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I also modified the Gradle VM options as `-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m` but still it gives the error.

If I remove the dependency it works fine. I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: Is there any way for you to show the console output (like it says at the last line of the  gradle output)

Comment: add Google play services to the dependices too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing this command `./gradlew assembleDebug` in my project directory showed the real culprit of the problem.

When I add facebook SDK dependency to my project it exceeds the limit of 64K methods in my dex file. Due to this the gradle build was failing.

I added `multiDexEnabled = true` into my build types in build.gradle file. And derive my custom application class from MultiDexApplication instead of Application.

This solved my issue.